# Swift 4 Passing data to another controller Whilst staying in the same controller without presenting

Tags: swift

I have a product viewcontroller contains the following:

```
class arProduct: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

// cart ready array
var cartArray = [String]()
var cartIcon: UIImage?
}
```

In which the user using the interface will finalize the product details and clicks "add to cart button"

I have another view controller called cart contains the following:

```
class arCart: UIViewController {

//var
var cartMasterArray = [[String]]()
var cartImageArray = [UIImage]() 
}
```

Usually what I'd do is do a prepare in product, setting arCart as a destination and assign variables. Once the performsegue is called everything works fine. However what I need here is something like this:

```
prepare (...) {
let destination = segue.destination as arCart!
destination.cartMasterArray.append(self.cartArray)
}
```

which works fine but that means I have to segue for this to work.
BUT, the user might not want to segue after add to cart is clicked, he might want to go to another product and append another product to the cart, only when he is finished he might go to cart, and he might not go to cart from product view.

So my question is, is there a way to pass data to the cart vc without having to segue to it? i.e a prepare that will set a value globally that can be used without a segue? how to store a variable in memory basically that is independent of controller cycle.

Thanks,

Edited as requested with code snippets.

Comment: Please work on the formatting of your English or post the code, as it is hard to understand which VCs you have and what they call.

Comment: Maybe use some `Manager` to store cart information and refresh VC on `viewWillAppear`. You usually don`t want to store data directly in VCs - create some logic layer. (and you should edit your question to be more readable).

Comment: If the cart VC is already instantiated, you could get a reference to it relative to the existing VC (this would depend on the structure of your app). However, a better way is probably to store the cart data in a separate data model behind the scenes (maybe saving it to UserDefaults) which the cart VC then reads when it loads. This would be more stable than just passing the data to a VC because if the cart VC ever gets deinitialised you will lose our data.

Comment: @Chris thank you UserDefaults did the trick:

`@IBAction func addToCartFunc(_ sender: Any) {
        // send variables to defaults
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        cartDefaultArray = defaults.object(forKey: "cartArray") as! [[String]]
        cartDefaultArray.append(cartArray)
        defaults.set(cartDefaultArray, forKey: "cartArray")
    }`

I don't know how to accept your comment as the answer, this is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @codeBasePlusPlus Great! I will add this as a proper answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a better way to do this. Saving your cart data to `UserDefaults` would be more stable than passing it between view controllers. Then simply read from `UserDefaults` when the cart view controller is loaded.

Here is an example:

```
let cartArray =["item1", "item2"]

let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set(cartArray, forKey: "cartArray")
```

Then when you need to load the cart data:

```
let savedCart = defaults.object(forKey: "cartArray") as? [String] ?? [String]()
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a model to hold your products, then a (singleton) data controller to handle the cart.

```
class Product {

   var name: String = ""
   var image: UIImage?
   // Any other attributes of the product

   // Add init(s) and method as appropriate to set-up products
}

struct Products {

    var products: [Product] = []

    func loadProducts() {
        // Load your list of products from somewhere
    }
}

struct Cart {

   private var itemsInCart: [Product] = []

   func addProductToCart(_ product: Product) {
       itemsInCart.append(product)
   }

   func productsInCart() -> [Product] {
       return itemsInCart
   }

   // Other methods to handle the cart
}

// Better for the cart view controller to access the data controller,  
// but you can set the cart data in the segue...

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let vc = segue.destination as? MyViewControllerClass {
        vc.cart = Cart.productsInCart()
    }
}
```

You can then access the products and cart data from anywhere in your app. Obviously you'll need to populate the products in some way, presumably from a server or a database.

You could also use delegates to communicate between view controllers.